# Unknown fatal exception at Runtime when using Fragments and lists

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Afternoon all,

I'm currently learning all about fragments and their use in android apps. I'm trying to populate a listView with an array of Strings. This sort of idea worked when I was populating the list without using fragments but at the moment it's throwing a runtime exception "Unable to start activity". A simple point at where to look would be much appreciated as I can't figure out the logcat reading.

The fragment is thus:

```
public class setupFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setup, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView); //the program seems to at this point

        String[] setups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setups);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, setups);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        return view;
    }
}
```

It's my first time posting java fragments, so any posting errors I apologize for. Cursory breakpoint debugging indicates that the program is breaking on the ListView declaration.

I can post some of the logcat on request, I'm not posting it at the moment due it being long and convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace: `ListView listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);`

with: `ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);`

You can't call `getView()` before returning one from `onCreateView()`.

`getView()` returns null.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks for the swift and concise response with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Replace getView() with view, returned object

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

String[] setups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setups);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, setups);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Cut this code and paste it inside onViewCreated method, you cannot get a reference of a view by calling getView() since that view is not attached to that fragment yet.

Also change your getView() to just view.

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView declaration should be as follows :

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()) to know more about getView() and Fragments. Basically the getView() method returns the root view of the fragment which is nothing but the view returned by onCreateView()